# How do I configure a Flatron L177WSB for 1440x900?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, resolution

I am using ubuntu 12.04 with Nvidia Geforce 6150SR graphic card.In 12.04 Ubuntu does not recognize a screen resolution 1440x900 for my monitor "Flatron L177WSB".I tried [this](http://anhe51.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/change-resolution-of-unknown-monitor-in-ubuntu-11-10/) method,but not working.It  fails from 5th step.
Terminal shows

> Failed to get size of gamma for output default

I am using AMD athlon 64x2,1GB memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, normaly this is caused by a problem with X.org reading the EDID file from your monitor with the resolutions...

The solution is to edit the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file like this :

If you don't have this file then you have to create it from scratch, just let the Nvidia software do it for you using this command on the terminal :

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

If you already have an `xorg.conf` file, then you'll just have to edit (or create one if he doesn't exist), as root, like this:

```
gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And copy this lines on the "Section Device":

```
    Option         "UseEDID" "true"
    Option         "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "CRT,DFP,TV"
```

If you are using and HDMI cable (for example), and the image is not scaled then add this line just after the other ones:

```
    Option         "FlatPanelProperties" "Scaling = Native"
```

Now just logout and login again, Open the "Nvidia X Server Settings" and see if all the resolutions available by your display are available.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The result is terrible.Now the only available resolution is 640x480.

Comment: Here is my xorg.conf as such..

Comment: Could you please remove the xorg file, logout and login, and then install read-edid like this "sudo apt-get install read-edid" and then write this on the terminal "sudo get-edid | sudo parse-edid", post it on "pastebin.com" (for example) and then send me the link so I can see the problem ?

Comment: how can i remove xorg file?

Comment: To remove use this command in the terminal "sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf"

Comment: this is what i got. http://pastebin.com/MfmMR6xc

Comment: weird.... just one question, have you trid to logout and login again after removing the xorg file ? Just to see if the Ubuntu Monitor Settings (and THEN the Nvidia Settings if the first one don't find the good resolution), could find the real resolution. Please test that before going any further.

Comment: yes.after removing xorg file I logout.After that the resolution was again changed back to 1024x768

Comment: Can you please do the fallowing 2 commands and show me the output (PS: I don't have Ubuntu installed right know I am on Arch Linux, so I don't know if those 2 packages are pre-installed, if not, then tell me so I can search what package to install)

1 - sudo ddcprobe
2 - sudo xresprobe nv

Comment: shows "command not found"-for both.how can i install?

Comment: Try "sudo apt-get install ddcprobe"

Comment: I mean "sudo apt-get install xresprobe"

Comment: ddc probe http://pastebin.com/fbhnP4R8

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UiSgA5Du

Comment: Ok I am gonna try something, just re-try the "sudo nvidia-xconfig" and then send me the result of your "/etc/X11/xorg.conf", I will edit it and send it back to you so you can test it until it detects your resolution, if you agree with this of course, since i don't find another solution :S

Comment: Here it is. http://pastebin.com/v00tpsn6

Comment: Try with this one http://pastebin.com/nWa59FTh just do "sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf" and remove all the text from the current file, and just copy-paste what I've send you, logout and login, and see if it works.

Comment: I've found the information here (http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1250971.html) someone with a similar problem, but using the same screen as you.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you install the Proprietary drivers or even have the Nvidia PPA (x-swat). So with that in mind I can offer the following help:

What I would suggest is to first delete the `monitors.xml` file that should solve some resolution problems. The file can be found in `~/.config`. Or go to a terminal and type `sudo rm -fr ~/.config/monitors.xml`

Now restart to see if it shows the resolution you want.

If the problem persists open the `nvidia-settings` GUI program. Go to dash an type `nvidia`, you should see the nvidia settings program. Open it and look for the resolution option in there. Test it out.

UPDATE: If you want `monitors.xml` back, here is mine, you can change the lines to fit your resolution:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="default">
          <vendor>???</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1680</width>
          <height>1050</height>
          <rate>56</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Comment: not working and res gone to 640x480.Again terrible

Comment: how can i replace that file?

Comment: Updated to include the monitors.xml content.

Answer (score 1):

1. open the NVIDIA X Server Settings and select the "X Server Display Configuration".
2. Click "Save toX Configuration File" and Check the path is "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
3. Modify here as you need.

   ```
   Section "Screen"
       Identifier     "Screen0"
       Device         "Device0"
       Monitor        "Monitor0"
       DefaultDepth    24
       Option         "Stereo" "0"
       Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
       Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +1920+180, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
       SubSection     "Display"
       Depth           24
       EndSubSection
   EndSection
   ```

   from

   ```
   nvidia-auto-select
   ```

   to

   ```
   1440x900_60
   ```
4. logout & login

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried obtaining your drivers from the nvidia site? [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html)

Comment: I have 295.53 thelatest one...